# Convergence of a series involving arcsin

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to determine the convergence of the following series. I tried a few tests but they turned inconclusive.
       $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\arcsin \frac 1{2^n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** apply the ratio test, noting that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\arcsin (1/2^n)}{(1/2^n)} = 1
$$

Comment: A more interesting approach: apply Jenen's inequality, noting that $-\sin x$ is concave on $(0,1)$

Answer (score 2):

$\arcsin' x = { 1 \over \sqrt{ 1 - x^2}}$, hence $\arcsin' 0= 1$. Hence for some $\delta>0$ we have ${\arcsin x \over x} \le 2x$ for $0<|x| < \delta$ (nothing special about $2$ other than $2>1$).

In particular, if $0 \le x < \delta$, we have $\arcsin x \le 2x$.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, so there exist $\epsilon >0$, that for $0<y< \epsilon$ is

$$\frac{\sin y}{y}>\frac{1}{2}$$

If you substitute $x=\arcsin y $ you have:

$$\frac{\sin \arcsin  x}{\arcsin x}=\frac{x}{\arcsin x}> \frac{1}{2}$$

So:

$$x> \frac{1}{2}\arcsin x$$

And:

$$\frac{1}{2^n}>\frac{1}{2}\arcsin \frac{1}{2^n}$$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** In the interval $0\le x\le \pi/2$ we have $x/2\le \sin x\le x$. So for positive $t$, we have $\arcsin t \le 2t$. Now use Comparison.